# Is there any consistent way to check whether the session is still alive in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, session, consistency

I have session's `SID` and `SERIAL#`. Is there any consistent way to check if the session is still alive and connected?

Right now my application uses simple query over `GV$SESSION` view to obtain that information. But it looks like the alive session may disappear from the view from time to time for couple of seconds and then it re-appears in the view again with the same `SID` and `SERIAL#`.

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/datadict.htm#CNCPT88897) says about Dynamic Performance Views like `GV$SESSION`:

> Dynamic performance views are based on virtual tables built from
>   database memory structures. Thus, they are not conventional tables
>   stored in the database. **Read consistency is not guaranteed** for the
>   views because the data is updated dynamically.

I think this is the reason, why my session disappears from `GV$SESSION`. Is there any other way to obtain this information consistently?

Comment: What problem are you trying to address by this query?

Comment: I have so called "Business Locks" functionality in my application. I store these locks as key value pairs in separate table along with `SID` and `SERIAL#` of the session which holds the lock. Later whenever some other session is trying to re-acquire the lock, I have to check whether the lock holder is still alive.

Comment: I can't say that I've ever seen a row disappear from `gv$session` for a couple of seconds.  You don't have any other predicates that might cause rows to be returned (or not)?  A `sid, serial#` combination can be reused later but that should take far more than a few seconds.  Are you actually using RAC or would it be reasonable to just use `v$session`?

Comment: @Justin Cave. Maybe if he's looking for ACTIVE sessions only, some rows may dissappear from time to time?

Comment: I don't have any other predicates. My query looks like this: `select count(1) into sessions_count from gv$session where sid=session_sid and serial# = session_serial;`

Comment: Also I suspect that the session disappears from `GV$SESSION` when oracle updates its `SQL_ID` field. I was able to reproduce the issue only on highly loaded sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like more reliable way to check if session is alive in Oracle is to use `DBMS_SESSION` package, namely [DBMS_SESSION.IS_SESSION_ALIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS68048) function.